# Using navigate react-router v6 in statement

Tags: reactjs

I used navigate in react-router v6. But It doesn't navigate to /search. I got data from API and want to compare it with the value of the search bar. If they are equal, navigate to /search; if they're not, navigate to /searchNull .I checked in the console. They were equal. But It is always navigated to /searchNull path. Do you have any solution?

**SearchInput.js**

```
import "./SearchInput.css";
import Search from "../../../assets/Images/icon/search-normal.svg";
import { useNavigate  } from "react-router-dom";
import { React , useRef , useState } from "react";
import { useAppContext }  from "../../../Context/SearchContext/SearchContext";

const SearchInput =(props)=>{

const [inputChange , setInputChanage ] =useState("");
const inputRef = useRef(null);
const navigate = useNavigate();
const {setSearchValue , bookData } = useAppContext();

const inputChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setInputChanage(event.target.value)
};

const handleKeyDown = (event) => {

  if (event.key === "Enter"){
        
    setSearchValue(inputRef.current.value);
        
    bookData.map((item) => {
            
      if( item.name.toString()  === inputChange.toString()){
        navigate("/search");            
      }
      else{
        navigate("/searchNull")
      }
    })  
   }

}

return(
    <div className="search-input-container">
        <input
        className="search-input"
        ref={inputRef} 
        onChange={inputChangeHandler}
        value={inputChange} type="text" 
        onKeyDown={handleKeyDown} placeholder= {props.placeholder}
        />
        <button className="search-icon" onClick={handleClick}>
          <img src={Search} width="100%" height="100%" alt="search icon" />
        </button>
    </div>
)
export default SearchInput;
```

I called API in **Context.js** :

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const CoinsContext = createContext({});

const SearchContext = ({ children }) => {

const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState(' ');
const [bookData , setBookData ] = useState([]);

useEffect(()=>{
axios
.post('/books/list/all').then((response)=>{
    const bookApi = [];
    response.data.data.map((item)=>{
        bookApi.push({
            id:item.id,
            name:item.name,
        })
    })
    setBookData(bookApi)
   })
 },[])
 return (
   <CoinsContext.Provider value={{ searchValue, setSearchValue ,bookData ,setBookData 
   }}>
     {children}
   </CoinsContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useAppContext = () => useContext(CoinsContext);
export default SearchContext;
```

Comment: You set `inputChange` state only where `event.key === "Enter"`. Maybe this is the problem? Try moving `setSearchValue(inputRef.current.value);` outside the if statement.

Comment: Another note: its not recommanded to use two sources to access the same data - you use both ref and state to access input's value.  It's redundant and can lead to confusion. You can and should only use state.

Comment: @Bar  If I move `setSearchValue(inputRef.current.value);` out of the statement, I will get error, because the value is null out of the statement. But I will use your recommendation.